# Android Studio não cria projeto novo

Tags: android, android-studio

Meu android studio sempre que crio um projeto, ele da esse erro:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:processDebugAndroidTestResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.3\aapt.exe''
>   finished with non-zero exit value -1073741819

Parou de funcionar de um dia para o outro, ja reinstalei ele, ja reinstalei o SDK Tools com API level 24, 25 e 26...
Ele não se limita a projetos novos, em projetos antigos ele não carrega tambem.

Comment: Já tentou ir em Build -> Clean Project ?

Comment: Pelo que entendi @Zulian, ele não esta nem conseguindo criar um projeto... Tenta reinstalar a JDK e a SDK para as versões mais recentes

Comment: Tenta dar um Build > Clean Project e depois Build > Rebuild Project. Se não resolver, tenta solucionar com as possíveis soluções nesse link >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249986/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value